# RegEx - removing preceding & trailing whitespace while matching contents

Tags: regex

I want to try and construct a RegEx statement that will remove any pre-ceeding or trailing white spaces from a string (but leave any contained within the string untouched) while also matching a chosen format. For instance the string must cannot be any longer than 20 characters, can contain any of the characters from a-zA-Z0-9 as well as underscores and hyphens. But most importantly it must trim or ignore any spaces found at either the start or end of the string so:

Correct:
"Have a nice day"

Incorrect:
" Have a nice day to "

I have tried many different ways of doing this but unfortunately so far I have not been able to come up with a formula that does exactly what I want. Could anyone help me with a suitable RegEx? (this is a RegEx in its simplest form and not platform specific).

Answer (score 4):

Search for this pattern:

```
^\s*(.*?)\s*$
```

Replace with this one:

```
\1
```

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `^\S((.{0,18}\S)|)$`

`^` begin of string

`\S` non-space symbol

`(.{0,18}\S)?` any symbol and non-space symbol at the end (0-19 symbols)

`|` or

`$` end of string

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your example that space is allowed in the middle of the string as well, so try this one

```
^((([a-zA-Z0-9\-_][a-zA-Z0-9\-_ ]{0,18}?[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]))|([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]))$
```

Anything which is matched is correct.

The `or` section in the pattern is used for supporting a single character sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^\S[\w\s-]{0,18}\S$
```

`18` is the `maxlength - 2` of the string, because of the two `\S` that will match any non whitespace char each. For example it this case, strings won't match if their length is higher than `20` chars. Moreover, strings won't match if their length is lower than `2` chars, due to the same above constraint.

Comment: your match lenght is [3,20], it's undocumented limitation

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using sed

```
echo "  Have a nice day  "|sed -E "s/^ *([^ ]+.*[^ ]+) +$/\\1/"
```