# Restrict strings in XSD so they don't have leading or trailing whitespace and only contain alphanumerics, hyphen and an underscore?

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I am trying to eliminate leading/trailing whitespaces and also want to make sure that my string doesn't contain special characters(except "-" and "_", I need these). From an other post I was able to come up with this

```
<xs:simpleType name="RandomString"> 
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\S([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\S)?"/> 
    </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
```

So far I was able to figure a way to not allow leading, trailing spaces and multiple special characters. But, I have this unique situation where it is allowing any one special character towards the end of the string

i.e Strings like `abcdef1234!@#` and `abc123!xyz` aren't allowed according to regex but something like `abc123!` or `random234@`(with only one special character ending the string) are not being caught by my regex. Am I missing something?

Comment: My reference to come up with above scenario : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815521/how-to-restrict-strings-in-xsd-so-they-dont-have-leading-or-trailing-whitespace

Comment: What characters you want to allow as leading/trailing in your string?

Comment: You just need `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Its just blank/whitespaces that I want to avoid in leading/trailing places in my string and obviously no special characters.

Comment: @pj0129: Do you want to allow spaces in middle of text? If not, then Wiktor's answer should be good enough for you.

Comment: Nope no spaces in between as well, but I just checked Wiktor's suggestion by making a simple java check `System.out.println("asdfgASDF_1  234-13746-ahgsd".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+"));` and it returned false

Comment: You can compactly write your regex as `[\w-]+` as this will allow all alphanumerics and underscore and hyphen.

Comment: True, but for some reason I don't know if it's my IDE or compiler but it is not recognizing `\w` so I explicitly mentioned the ranges I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches the unwelcome strings because `\S` matches *any* non-whitespace char.

Your `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` character class does not match a whitespace, so you may omit `\S` pattern altogether and use

```
<xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+"/>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AerIrU/1).

Comment: Yes Wiktor, now it all makes sense I was allowing it myself at the first `\S` in my pattern. Thanks your solution helped.